# jQuery next select element on row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 select boxes in my html called type and brand. When the type is changed i use the onchange event to create a ajax request to the server and retrieve the brands which produce the products in the type field. That is all working fine but i need to load the retrieved data in the brand select and i don't know how to do that because i have multiple rows containing type and brand select boxes. How can i find the next select element on the same row as the changed type?

My code
HTML:

```
<tr>
<td>
    <select id="type" onchange="on_part_type_changed(this)" name "type[]"> --[options]-- </select>
</td>
<td>
    <select id="brand" name="brand[]"></select>
</td>
</tr>
```

Javascript:

```
function on_part_type_changed(selectObject) {
    // ajax call here (works)

    // now need to update the brand select that is on the same row as selectObject (jQuery)
}
```

Comment: Like this, http://www.codexworld.com/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using-jquery-ajax-php/

Comment: `$(event.target).next('select').html(...)` or `$(this).next('select').html(...)`

Comment: You can't have multiple IDs of `type` and `brand`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the brand object before you do the ajax call.  It'll be ready for you once the ajax response comes back.

```
function on_part_type_changed(selectObject) {
     //clumsy way of finding the brand object nextdoor  
     var brandObj=selectObject.parent().next().children('.brand');
     // ajax call here
     someKindOfAjax(response) {
         //put response into brand object we got earlier
         brandObj.html(response);
     }
}
```

As others have said, if there can be multiple selects that are "brand", it should be a class instead of an ID.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function on_part_type_changed(selectObject) {
    $(selectObject).next('.brand').html('...');
}
```